# Trigonometry accelerometer Z angle from gravity vector (normal vector to X Y plane)

Tags: python, trigonometry, accelerometer, angle

This one has had me scratching my head for a while. I have an accelerometer and am successfully measuring the X and Y angles with this great script: https://github.com/ozzmaker/BerryIMU/blob/master/python-BerryIMU-gryo-accel-compass/berryIMU.py

What I would like to calculate is the delta angle between the gravity vector and the Z axis (where Z is the normal vector to the plane created by the X and Y angles).

I have found some images on google and edited them to try to explain the issue. See below.

[Angle of Z to gravity vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCxbf.png)

If the script from githut above calculates X and Y as follows:

```
import math

RAD_TO_DEG = 57.295
ACCy = (see github script for details)
ACCz = (see github script for details)
ACCx = (see github script for details)


Xangle =  (math.atan2(ACCy,ACCz)*RAD_TO_DEG)
Yangle =  (math.atan2(ACCz,ACCx)*RAD_TO_DEG)
```

How would I calculate the Z angle delta to gravity vector as shown in the image? Would it be:

```
Zangle = (math.atan2(ACCx,ACCy)*RAD_TO_DEG)
```

Comment: Hi @L.C.! You question is something I think might be extremely useful for me. However, I haven't found the GitHub for more info. Could you please add perhaps some info to the question? I'd appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
math.asin(ACCz / math.sqrt(ACCx ** 2 + ACCy **2 + ACCz ** 2)) * RAD_TO_DEG
```

might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it and it works. I took the accelerometer and placed it on a fixed angle slope, and rotated it on the slope with the base of the board always in contact with the slope surface. The new Zangle above is constant and the X and Y change as you spin the board. Well done.